# Размер html страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему когда заливаю сайт на хостинг он как бы масштабируется и элементы увеличиваются?

Tags: html5, хостинг, разметка, масштабирование

На локальном хосте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он же на обычном хостинге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем это происходит со всеми элементами - они увеличены.

Comment: Если нажать `Ctrl`+`0`, не восстанавливается?

Comment: Нет. Такое впечатление что увеличивается только ширина html страницы.

Comment: На локальном размер окна: 1498.89 х 707.78, а в реале даже когда открываю просто файл html 1349x637

Comment: Попробуйте ctrl-0 на локальном хосте

Comment: Точно!) Я в шоке)) Спасибо))